# AzureDevOps: Bug Creation with Resolved to Field and Tags Addition

Tags: azure-devops

I have a service to create bugs and using the below Documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Question is that,

a. Since service account(say:abc) is creating bug, once bugs gets resolved, its getting assigned to that same service account(abc). Is here a way i can hardcode to assign to someone say:xyz while bug is getting created.  Or

Is there any JsonPathOperation Path that i can use to solve this?

b. What is JsonPathOperation Path for adding the tags to the Bug?

Appreciate any help or please direct to any references

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the following code:

a.

```
patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add,
        Path = "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        Value = "***@***.com"//Accound Name
    }
);
```

b.

```
patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add,
        Path = "/fields/System.Tags",
        Value = "tag"//Tag Name
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Regarding (a), i was actually looking OnBehalf Of, but i found how to do it and not sure that feature is available publicly.